# Query get data in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have problem with query cakephp3.x . i want return data have like project_id return a list name inside project_id,
But project_id is unique.unduplicated project_id.
sorry my english.please help.

```
$result = $query->find('all', [
                        'fields' => [
                            'project_id' => 't_project_member.project_id',
                            'project_name' => 't_project.name',
                            'member_name' => 'concat(t_member.first_name," ",t_member.last_name)'
                        ],
                        'join' => [
                            ['table' => 't_project', 
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => 't_project.id = t_project_member.project_id'],

                            ['table' => 't_member', 
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => 't_member.id = t_project_member.member_id'],

                        ],
                        'conditions' => ['t_project.id' => $project_id]
                ]);
```

Result:

```
 {
 "result": [
    {
        "project_id": 4,
        "project_name": "Ueno Rebrand : Business cards #1",
        "member_name": "User_3 c"
    },
    {
        "project_id": 4,
        "project_name": "Ueno Rebrand : Business cards #1",
        "member_name": "User_4 d"
    },
    {
        "project_id": 4,
        "project_name": "Ueno Rebrand : Business cards #1",
        "member_name": "User_5 e"
    },
  ]
}
```

I want return data like below.

```
{
 "result": [
    {
        "project_id": 4,
        "project_name": "Ueno Rebrand : Business cards #1",
        "member_name": {
                        "User_3 c",
                        "User_4 d",
                        "User_5 e
                       }
    },
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Group By `project_id`, may be that help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP and GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929666/cakephp-and-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $query->find('all', [
                        'fields' => [
                            'project_id' => 't_project_member.project_id',
                            'project_name' => 't_project.name',
                            'member_name' => 'concat(t_member.first_name," ",t_member.last_name)'
                        ],
                        'join' => [
                            ['table' => 't_project', 
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => 't_project.id = t_project_member.project_id'],

                            ['table' => 't_member', 
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => 't_member.id = t_project_member.member_id'],

                        ],
                        'group' => '`t_project_member`.`project_id`',
                        'conditions' => ['t_project.id' => $project_id]
                ]);
```